# Is it possible to open a stargate within a stargate?

Tags: stargate

What would happen if an activated stargate were placed inside a bigger activated stargate? What if there were two stargates close and parallel to each other, one is already activated and the second activates making the vortex go through the event horizon of the first one?

Do Stargate physics mention this scenario?

Comment: I don't really think a canonical answer can be given here.

Comment: i would assume the best you can get is a floating Atlantis style gate getting sent through an open supergate, the atlantis gate would probably just close, as it no longer had the power to reach the destination.

Comment: I've voted to close. I'm certain this didn't happen in-canon and "What-if" questions are off topic.

Comment: This is a big gaping hole in the logic of stargate when it introduced gates of different sizes.  Never explained on screen.

Comment: @Tritium21 are you referring to the supergate?

Comment: @Himarm Amongst other things.  The Tolan gate was also not to standard size.

Comment: Nothing would happen. The smaller gate would close automatically. Do you think an alien species sophisticated enough to create wormholes would not consider the possibility that someone might try to sabotage a gate by throwing a smaller one into a bigger one? The smaller gate is defaulted to shutting down due to proximity to the larger gate to prevent such accidents from happening. This failsafe would work even if you didn't want it to. Hollywood has a habit of making aliens less intelligent than they need to be. Good engineering would prevent this from happening, most assuredly.

Comment: @Thaddeus - Either that or an [enormous explosion](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/Jumpgate#Bonehead_Maneuver).

Comment: Thad, the Ancients were very smart, but both humans and goa'uld learned to bypass and reengineer the star gate controls. After all, we got multiple stargates activating at the same time.

Comment: This **Can** be answered though. In canon, only one gate in an active gravity well can be active at the same time. See the episodes revolving the Russian and artic gates.

Comment: @cde is correct. It is impossible for two stargates, of any size, to be active in the same gravity well at the same time. This is a law of stargate physics, much like the 38 minute limit on the gate being open, excepting power surges. Therefore, the proposed scenario can never take place.

Comment: Man,  I remember a ton of other support against this being possible all from sg1 canon too

Comment: Actually, it can be proven *in universe* that having two Stargates open at the same time is possible. Towards the end of Atlantis (I believe) they had moved gates together to form a gate network. They would open a series of gates at the same time and jump through all of them. There was a midway point due to a maximum of jumps or some such. I believe the gates were faced front to front, though, but half of the entire string was opened at once. I believe this was to get people from Atlantis to Earth easily. -- This may end up being contradictory to some other answers, so this could be fun.

Comment: And what would happen if it did, well,  kinda. Vote to re open

Comment: The episode you can find the string-o-rings is in [Midway](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1169919/) (S4E17). @cde ... I'm just saying that and not that this should be reopened. I believe the original question is flawed and it being closed as opinion is well deserved.

Comment: @Paulster2: The gate bridge you're talking about didn't involve opening 2 gates at once. They would "store and forward" whatever was in the gate to the next one, which was a significant distance away. The two gates facing each other in the middle were from different gate systems (Pegasus/Milky Way) and the traveler would exit one and rematerialize and then dial and enter the other gate system to move to their final destination.

Comment: @geewhiz ... You could be right ... been a while since I watched it. Thanks for correcting me! I read on IMDB the reason for the center stop was a 24 hour quarantine.

Comment: @Paulster2 Answering with "the question is flawed due to _insert evidence here_" is a valid way of answering a question, even if it's not what the asker was looking for.  It just doesn't happen often

Comment: @Izkata ... I hadn't thought of that. Even so, my evidence was flawed (which seems to happen quite often, lol).

Comment: @Paulster2: In addition to what geewhiz stated, those gates were not in the same gravity well. They were midway between the Milky Way and Pegasus galaxies, with no stars for a considerable distance in either direction. The biggest gravity source they were competing with was each other; the arrival of the *Daedalus* or another Tauri vessel was presumably the biggest gravitational flux the Midway station would ever have to face. This lack of a gravity well means that "Midway" does not contradict earlier episodes that state stargates cannot operate in the same gravity well at the same time.

Comment: @Tritium21: What? It's not a "big gaping hole in logic" at all. Why does it need to be "explained on screen"? A Stargate is a device that maintains a wormhole, and I don't see how _LOGICALLY_ it can do so when it's been dematerialised. So _LOGIC_ dictates that the answer is plainly obvious to anyone with half a brain.